# Помогите упростить пример для phatomjs

Tags: phantomjs

Помогите упростить вот этот пример с git hub
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js 
Я так понял он ждет наступление события или таймаута.

Помогите переделать под мой пример, у меня на странице есть блок например:

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

В качестве примера его событие изменяется вот так вот

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = '<b>Новое содержимое</b>';
}, 2000);
```

Подскажите как поменять тот пример что бы он слушал событие изменение содержимого   или через 10 сек. завершил работу?